# MYSQL | Syntax Error though everything is correctly written

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to read data from my MySql Database using node js. I'm actually already doing it in another file and there it works fine!
I'm using:

```
console.log('GuildId: ' + guildId);

let MemberCountChannel = new Map();{

connection.promise().query( guildId,
    `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${guildId}'`
).then(result => {
    MemberCountChannel.set(guildId, result[0][0].memberCountId);
    MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(guildId);

console.log(MemberCountChannelId);
```

I know that the GuildId is right 'cause it logs it right in the beginning of my code.
When executing that code I get the following:

```
GuildId: 776182101337833474
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '776182101337833474' at line 1
    at PromiseConnection.query (/home/ubuntu/discord-bot-v2/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:92:22)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/discord-bot-v2/counters/member-counter.js:20:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '776182101337833474' at line 1"
}
```

I already tried changing '${guildId}' to just the guild Id:

```
console.log('GuildId: ' + guildId);

    let MemberCountChannel = new Map();{

    connection.promise().query( guildId,
        `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '776182101337833474'`
    ).then(result => {
        MemberCountChannel.set(guildId, result[0][0].memberCountId);
        MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(guildId);

    console.log(MemberCountChannelId);
```

But using this I got the same output. My Database Table looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM GuildConfigurable;
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| guildId            | cmdPrefix | radioChannelId | memberCountId | AutoStartRadio |
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| 776182101337833474 | <         | N/A            | N/A           | N              |
| 791351561182904381 | <         | N/A            | N/A           | N              |
| 804867729404067904 | <         | N/A            | N/A           | N              |
+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And when typing this in the console:

```
SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = 776182101337833474;
or
SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '776182101337833474';
```

I get the output I need:

```
SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = 776182101337833474;
+---------------+
| memberCountId |
+---------------+
| N/A           |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any Ideas why I get this error? I'm pretty sure there is no syntax error.

```
EDIT:
```

I already completely reinstalled mysql2 and mysql-server and I'm using the mostly same script in another file to get cmdPrefix:

```
var guildId = message.guild.id; 
    getMemberCount(client, guildId);

    let guildCommandPrefix = new Map();
    connection.promise().query(
        `SELECT cmdPrefix FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${message.guild.id}'`
    ).then(result => {
        guildCommandPrefix.set(message.guild.id, result[0][0].cmdPrefix);
        prefix = guildCommandPrefix.get(message.guild.id);
```

And this one works fine...

Comment: I suggest to log the query and then copy-paste under a tool like Adminer or PhpMyAdmin. to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection.promise().query( guildId,
    `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '${guildId}'`
)
```

Are you sure that the first parameter should be the ID? Should it not rather be the query?

Comment: https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b

Comment: I agree, the first parameter should be the query

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semicolon at the end of the SELECT statment:

```
connection.promise().query( guildId,
        `SELECT memberCountId FROM GuildConfigurable WHERE guildId = '776182101337833474';`
    ).then(result => {
        MemberCountChannel.set(guildId, result[0][0].memberCountId);
        MemberCountChannelId = MemberCountChannel.get(guildId);
```

Comment: Changed nothing... It doesn't even show the semicolon in the error message...